# Dont allow access to txt files in root via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have custom MVC framework and my .htaccess file rewrites rules to send all requests via index.php which then routes the requests.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|JPG|gif|png|PNG|ico|pdf|swf|xml|pem)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Problem is that I have some **.txt** files in public_html folder where index.php and `.htaccess` reside. Is it possible to not allow users access .txt files? Right now If I visit `www.MyURL/test.txt` I can view the txt file. But if I did `www.MyURL/cont/action/param1` would work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just block all `.txt` files using:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.txt$ - [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|JPG|gif|png|PNG|ico|pdf|swf|xml|pem)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```